# How to notify current activity from previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activities. 
I have an activity in which i need to get facebook friends data , their events , and 
save all this data to the database and then show a page with specific information but all 
this takes a lot of time. So before doing all this i move an intent to another activity 
and so the Activity #1 goes in background creating parsers and saving it in database. 
But now i need to notify my Activity #2 when all the computations is done so that i can 
enable some UI Buttons as well to show the data which is now stored in database.

Comment: Do you need Activity 1 for something else than loading? If not, then the way you designed your app flow is wrong. When Activity goes background (it's paused, stopped) then nothing you launched there won't continue to work (unless you put it in another thread in an AsyncTask or IntentService or so...).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need both of those Activities (because you don't need Activity#1 if it's only task is to download data), then `AsyncTask` will be no good, since it's designed to be attached to a specific `Activity`.

What you'd rather do is to start a `Service` (with `AsyncTask` in it or even better, an `IntentService`). When it finishes its job you could do something like this:

```
Intent finish = new Intent(com.mypackage.intent.ACTION_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE);
sendBroadcast(finish);
```

And in your Activity#2 listen to this broadcast with [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).